# Referencing JQuery correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, vb.net

I am trying to use Jquery for the first time and I am getting an issue.  I am using VS 2013, asp.net and VB.

My head tag is as follows.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="StyleSheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EDGE" /> 
    <script src="Bin/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function ()  {
            $('#LowerText').hide();
            $('#UpperText').hide();
            $('#AssetStatusChoice').change(function () {
                if($('#AssetStatusChoice').val("Fully Available"))
                {
                    $('#CommentsText').hide();
                }
                if ($('#AssetStatusChoice').val("Restricted"))
                {
                    $('#UpperLimit').show();
                    $('#LowerLimit').show();
                }
                if ($('#AssetStatusChoice').val("Unavailable"))
                {
                    $('#Commentstext').show();
                }
            });
        });


    </script>
</head>
```

When I debug the page I get the following error.

> 0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined

It seems from Googling the error that I am not referencing the js file correctly.  Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you sure, that your file is called `jquery-1.10.2.js`? Because normally it is either `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` or `jquery-1.10.2.debug.js`

Comment: Check you path to your jquery library file is correct.

Comment: Try moving the jquery file from `/bin` to something like `/js`. I'm not positive, but I believe the `bin` directory is reserved for compiled dlls and can't be accessed from the browser.

Comment: Do you really have the JS file in BIN folder?? Not an answer to your question, but you should move it to a Scripts folder or so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>` and Remove the 
`<script src="Bin/jquery-1.10.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>` Just use a host Jquery instead of adding it to you source. Read more :

[3 reasons why you should use hosted jQuery](http://www.google.co.za/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDQQFjAB&url=http://encosia.com/3-reasons-why-you-should-let-google-host-jquery-for-you/&ei=3-ChUtGRO4KWhQfQpIDACw&usg=AFQjCNFoTA7iC2eJnFdUgtaer1aVNWMOTA&sig2=qqHVXfI1b3OxABwqZG2ApA&bvm=bv.57752919,d.ZG4&cad=rja)

Comment: I would suggest `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com...` instead so you won't get warnings if running over HTTPS.

Comment: Well that allows my page to load.  My jquery doesn't seem to work thorugh :-(

Comment: I recommend adding a local fallback, though. Just in case the CDN version isn't available.

Answer (score 2):

IIS doesn't serve content in the /bin directory.
Move it to another directory like /scripts or /js or /scripts/lib, something like that. The bin directory is a bad place to put script files.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of options here. You could use the Google CDN by adding the following to your header:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or, as it appears you're using .NET, you could do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<%=ResolveClientUrl("~/Bin/jquery-1.10.2.js") %>"></script>
```

The second option gives you the additional advantage that when used in a master page can be used in any content pages at any file system level and it will still resolve correctly.

As Stefan has also said, I'd recommend moving your jQuery file from your bin directory.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the jQuery file in some other folder, like Scripts, or js, and in Solution Explorer check to see all files. Find the jQuery file you just copied, include it in the project, then drag it on the page where you want to place it. A correct script tag will be created.